# Error al obtener el nombre del pc cliente desde el servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net, servidor, dns, websocket

que tal, resulta que tengo un problema en mi sito de producción, que cuando publico mi codigo, me sale el siguiente error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Host desconocido

La razón es porque estoy tratando de obtener el nombre del pc en un equipo del cliente. Cuando pruebo con los siguientes codigos, el problema es el mismo:

```
String Hostname = System.Environment.MachineName;
String nombrePC = Hostname;
```

o con

```
String nombrePC =   System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName
```

En mi equipo de desarrollo localhost, no tengo ningun problema, pero cuando navego al sitio de producción, ahí sucede lo descrito.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, se lo agradecería mucho. No se que convendría mas, configurar el servidor, o cambiar la linea de código para obtener el nombre del equipo. Prefería hacer la corrección desde el código

Comment: El codigo asp.net se ejecuta en el servidor, no en el cliente, por lo que no es posible acceder al nombre del pc cliente desde tu aplicacion.

Comment: pero habría forma de hacerlo?

Comment: A priori no. Javascript (y en general todo lo que se ejecuta en un navegador web) no tiene acceso al equipo cliente en ningun caso por seguridad. Si tu aplicación corre en una red local, tal vez habría alguna forma (tendria que pensarlo) pero no, no se puede.

Comment: para que necesitas el nombre del equipo? te serviría la dirección Ip o el nombre del usuario?

Comment: necesito el nombre del equipo para se muestre en cada pc que son cajas de pago.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esta función por lo menos es lo que me ha funcionado a mi en mi sistema en producción, obteniendo el nombre del DNS del servidor de producción:

```
public string GetClientHostIP() {
        string clientIP = string.Empty;
        string hostName = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            clientIP = Request.UserHostAddress;
            hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.UserHostAddress).HostName;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Ip solo para que no de error sino esta registrada la pc en el DNS
            clientIP = "0.0.0.0";
            hostName = "PCError";
        }

        return hostName + " - " + clientIP;

    }
```

He invocas a la función desde donde deseas obtener el nombre del equipo.

Comment: no funciona en producción